# RuntimeError: `lengths` array must be sorted in decreasing order when `enforce_sorted` is True. - Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

It have been 5 hours sitting here getting the same error:

```
RuntimeError: `lengths` array must be sorted in decreasing order when `enforce_sorted` is True. You can pass `enforce_sorted=False` to pack_padded_sequence and/or pack_sequence to sidestep this requirement if you do not need ONNX exportability.
```

I'm working on this simple sentiment classification task using `RNN` in pytorch. I'm loading the my custom data using `torchtext`. I'm loading it from a json file which looks as follows:

```json
{"reviewText": "Da Silva takes the divine by ....", "overall": 4.0, "summary": "An amazing first novel"}
```

I created my `field` as follows. And i created a pre-processing `get_sentiment()` function that convert overalls that are greater than 2 to 1 0 otherwise:

```py
get_sentiment = lambda x: 1 if x >=3 else 0

TEXT = data.Field(tokenize = 'spacy',
                  tokenizer_language = 'en_core_web_sm',
                  include_lengths=True
                  )
LABEL = data.Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False, preprocessing=get_sentiment)

fields = {
    'reviewText': ('review', TEXT),
    'overall': ('sentiment', LABEL)
}
```

I loaded the data:

```
train_data, test_data = data.TabularDataset.splits(
    path="/content/",
    train="Books_small_10000.json",
    test="Books_small.json",
    format="json",
    fields=fields
)
```

I built the vocabularies:

```py
MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 25_000

TEXT.build_vocab(
    train_data,
    max_size = MAX_VOCAB_SIZE,
    vectors = "glove.6B.100d",
    unk_init = torch.Tensor.normal_
)

LABEL.build_vocab(train_data)
```

I created my iterators.

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_iterator, validation_iterator, test_iterator = data.BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, validation_data, test_data),
    device = device,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    sort_key = lambda x: len(x.review),
)
```

#### This is how my Model looks.

```py
class AmazonLSTMRNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers
               , bidirectional, dropout, pad_idx):
    super(AmazonLSTMRNN, self).__init__()

    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim=embedding_size, padding_idx=pad_idx)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, 
                        bidirectional=bidirectional, num_layers=num_layers,
                        dropout=dropout)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, out_features=output_size)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

  def forward(self, text, text_lengths):
    embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(text))
    packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths.to('cpu'))
    packed_output, (h_0, c_0) = self.rnn(packed_embedded)
    output, output_lengths = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(packed_output)
    h_0 = self.dropout(torch.cat((h_0[-2,:,:], h_0[-1,:,:]), dim = 1))
    return self.fc(h_0)


INPUT_DIM = len(TEXT.vocab) # # 25002
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
HIDDEN_DIM = 256
OUTPUT_DIM = 1
N_LAYERS = 2
BIDIRECTIONAL = True
DROPOUT = 0.5
PAD_IDX = TEXT.vocab.stoi[TEXT.pad_token] # 0
amazon_model = AmazonLSTMRNN(INPUT_DIM, 
            EMBEDDING_DIM, 
            HIDDEN_DIM, 
            OUTPUT_DIM, 
            N_LAYERS, 
            BIDIRECTIONAL, 
            DROPOUT, 
            PAD_IDX)

criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(amazon_model.parameters())
amazon_model = amazon_model.to(device)
criterion = criterion.to(device)
```

.....

#### Training function

```py
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion):
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    model.train()
    for batch in iterator:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        text, text_lengths = batch.review
        predictions = model(text, text_lengths).squeeze(1)
        loss = criterion(predictions, batch.sentiment)
        acc = accuracy(predictions, batch.sentiment)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

#### Training loop.

```
N_EPOCHS = 5
best_valid_loss = float('inf')
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    start_time = time.time()
    train_loss, train_acc = train(amazon_model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion)
    end_time = time.time()
    epoch_mins, epoch_secs = epoch_time(start_time, end_time)
    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(amazon_model.state_dict(), 'best-model.pt')
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Epoch Time: {epoch_mins}m {epoch_secs}s')
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
```

If someone knows where am i wrong please correct me. Any help input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some few minutes I found the solution and I was able to get accuracy of aprox `~93%` on a single training epoch.

I changed my `LABEL` field to:

```py
LABEL = data.LabelField(preprocessing=get_sentiment, dtype = torch.float)
```

Then i changed my `AmazonLSTMRNN` model in the forward method by adding `enforce_sorted=False` to the `pack_padded_sequence`.

The `forward` method:

```py
 def forward(self, text, text_lengths):
    embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(text))
    packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths.to('cpu'), enforce_sorted=False)
    packed_output, (h_0, c_0) = self.lstm(packed_embedded)
    output, output_lengths = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(packed_output)
    h_0 = self.dropout(torch.cat((h_0[-2,:,:], h_0[-1,:,:]), dim = 1))
    return self.fc(h_0)
```